# SQL Server Gantt Chart of Jobs

Tags: sql-server, outlook, calendar, backup

Need a graphical representation of my Job run-times in SQL Server.

I would like to know if there is a software or solution for getting the jobs in to a calendar looking format or Gantt style. I was hoping to have it in Outlook calendar, but it doesn't have to be.

How do most DBAs chart what jobs/backups are running at certain times? I've looked online and found that such information is not easy to come by.

Microsoft Project is out of the question (too expensive).

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Thanks. I clicked one the link you provided.